# How can I create extra columns during resampling a Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

if I have a dataframe like this:

```
timestamp      price
1596267946298  100.0
1596267946299  101.0
1596267946300  102.0
1596267948301  99.0
1596267948302  98.0
1596267949303  99.0
```

and I want to create the high, low and average during resampling:

I can duplicate the price column into a high and low column and then during resample do the min, max and mean on the appropriate columns.

But I was wondering if there is a way to make this in one pass?

my expected output would be (let's assume resampling at 100ms for this example)

```
timestamp      price   min  mean   max  
1596267946298  100.0   100  100.5  101
1596267946299  101.0   100  100.5  101
1596267946300  102.0   98   99.5   102
1596267948301  99.0    98   99.5   102
1596267948302  98.0    98   99.5   102
1596267949303  99.0    98   995.   102
```

Comment: What you want exactly is a little unclear to me. Can you give an expected output?

Comment: @busybear, I edited the question; I'm trying to do 3 operations on a single column / pass and then generate the additional columns at that time. Otherwise, I'd have to copy the price into a max column for example and apply a max operation to it, same for the min and mean.

Comment: So the min , max and mean are for every 100ms ?

Comment: in this case it would be a 100ms resample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could something like this-

```py
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)


def custom_func(x):
    return x[-1], x.min(), x.max(), x.mean()


result = series.resample('3T').apply(custom_func)
print(pd.DataFrame(result.tolist(), columns=['resampled', 'min', 'max', 'mean'], index=result.index))
```

#### Before resampling

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
2000-01-01 00:04:00    4
2000-01-01 00:05:00    5
2000-01-01 00:06:00    6
2000-01-01 00:07:00    7
2000-01-01 00:08:00    8
```

#### After resampling

```
                     resampled  min  max  mean
2000-01-01 00:00:00          2    0    2   1.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00          5    3    5   4.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00          8    6    8   7.0
```

Comment: you can replace x[-1] with x[0] which seems to be default behavior of pandas

Comment: one quick question: if the source dataframe has more columns, how would you split the tuple generated by the custom_func into new columns, while keeping the other columns? For example if you have: df = df.resample('1min').agg({'price': custom_func,
 'some_other_column':np.mean})

Comment: Not sure. Would've to iterate through either the columns or the tuples that you get later